# Pegar pedaço de texto dentro de uma palavra javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso verificar se existe um pedaço especifico dentro de um trecho de uma palavra em javascript.

Exemplo, a minha a palavra é João, preciso verificar se o Jo contem dentro dela.

Tentei fazer com o indexOf mas não deu, com o match mas não deu.

```
//pesquiso tudo que tem dentro dessa classe
$(".form-group").find('*').each(function() {
    var cont = 0;
    //pego todos os ids 
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //verifico se o trecho especifico contem o que eu preciso
    if (id.match("txtOutrosNomes") != -1) {
        console.log(cont++);
    }
});
```

Como fazer essa comparação?

Comment: O que tem dentro de `url`?

Comment: ops, é id ao invés da url

Comment: Bom, mas o que exatamente aparece em `id`? Parece bem simples o que você quer fazer, o [indexOf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262882/5043), o [match](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262884/5043) ou até mesmo um [Regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262883/5043) deveriam funcionar. Talvez seja outro problema...

Comment: Aparece coisa do tipo "txtOutrosNomes2", "txtOutrosNomes1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá
Creio que você possa fazer com Regex, por exemplo:

```
var w = "João";
var r = /Jo/i;
r.test(w) //retorna true...
```

Comment: Dessa forma funcionou

Answer (score 3):

`match` irá retornar o texto combinado, então você poderia alterar seu código dessa forma que irá checar se é diferente de nulo:

```js
let url = "João";

if (url.match("Jo")) {
  console.log("Match");
}
```

É importante verificar se as comparações irão ser corretas, talvez você poderá desejar desconsiderar casos sensíveis (*cases sensitives*), acentuação e/ou espaços.

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro converter tanto a string que quer buscar quanto o texto onde será feita a busca em minúsculas, assim evitará que a string não seja encontrada pelo fato do JavaScript ser *case insentivive*. Então você pode usar `indexOf`:

```
$(".form-group").find('*').each(function() {
    var cont = 0;
    //pego todos os ids 
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //verifico se o trecho especifico contem o que eu preciso
    if (id.toLowerCase().indexOf("txtOutrosNomes".toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        console.log(cont++);
    }
});
```

Neste caso, irá achar tanto "Jo" quanto "jo" em "João".

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `IndexOf()`

Quando retorna -1 a string não foi encontrada

```
var text = this.variable;
var term = "jo";

if( text.indexOf( term ) != -1 )
    alert(term);
```

Comment: Então por isso coloquei != -1

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função match(). <[leia mais](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)>

```js
function contem(frase, palavra){
  if(frase != null && palavra != null){
    if(frase.match(palavra))
      return 'contem';
  }
  return 'não contem';
}


var txtContem = document.getElementById('contem');
txtContem.value = contem('João comeu pão', 'Jo');
```

```html
<input type="text" id="contem" placeholder="contém ou não">
```

Dê também uma lida em [expressões regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (regex). Com ela os seus tratamentos de string ficaram bem melhores. No exemplo que dei acima eu não usei regex para se adequar com o que você estava fazendo anteriormente.